# This code is not running the else statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

**When I input any number that is neither a multiple of 2 nor 5, the output is still the one I set for the first *if* statement**

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if num%2 or num%5:
    print(num)

else:
    print("Not a multiple")
```

Comment: else part should be executed for 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will keep asking forever

```
while True:
  num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  if (num%2 == 0 or num%5 == 0):
      print(num)
  else:
      print("Not a multiple")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should mention the '==0' portion in if statement.

I have made the changes.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if (num%2 or num%5)==0:#I have changed the if statement here
    print(num)

else:
    print("Not a multiple")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # what is is checking for

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))


if num%2 == 2 or num%5 == 2: 
    print(num)

else: 
    print("Not a multiple")

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if num%2 == 0 or num%5 == 0: 
    print(num)

else: 
    print("Not a multiple")
```